# Rust giving error for Option<usize> when using variable inside of method

Tags: rust

I am very new to Rust and decided my first program to be a brainfuck interpreter.
I plan on using jump tables as the solution for the loops.
However I decided to rewrite the method to make it look better (for my tastes) and i got an error that I can't quite understand why

Code before causes no errors:

```
fn process_jumps(jump_map: &mut Vec<usize>, instructions: &Vec<Inst>){
    let mut stack: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
    for (i, inst) in instructions.iter().enumerate() {
        match inst {
            Inst::LoopOpen => stack.push(i),
            Inst::LoopClose => {
                jump_map[i] = stack.pop();
                jump_map[jump_map[i]] = i;
            }
            _ => ()
        }
    }
}
```

Code after has an error (marked in code):

```
fn process_jumps(instructions: &Vec<Inst>) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut jump_table: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
    let mut stack: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
    for (i, inst) in instructions.iter().enumerate() {
        match inst {
            Inst::LoopOpen => stack.push(i),
            Inst::LoopClose => {
                jump_table[i] = stack.pop(); // expected `usize`, found `Option<usize>`
                jump_table[jump_map[i]] = i;
            }
            _ => ()
        }
    }
    return jump_table;
}
```

My main question is why my code before didn't need me to check the optional?

Comment: The first code snippet [does error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68345268fa8873643bf3acde8b0063b6) though. Or is `vec<usize>` there not a typo but a custom type?

Comment: @cafce25 that was a typo, I fixed it

Comment: @cafce25 and I take that back, I am an idiot. Now it correctly throws an error...

Comment: This is a good way to handle the jumps. Note: when you DO get None because the stack is empty, that means you should terminate, reporting it as a syntax error in the brainfuck program: "unmatched ']' at byte (i)" or something like that.

Comment: Similarly, before returning the jump table you should make sure that the stack is empty at that point, and if not, everything on it is unmatched '['s, you could pop and report those as a syntax error and terminate, or just the most recent one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vec`'s [pop()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.pop) method returns `Option<T>`, not `T`.

You need to get the `usize` value from inside that `Option`, just make sure you've handled the `None` case correctly. When you are sure `None` is not possible, the simplest thing you could do is to [`unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) it.

Neither of your examples should really compile, as they both try to assign `Option<usize>` to a `Vec<usize>`.